# CRM 2013 On premise Authentication Error while retrieving

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I have created a batch job and created the iorganisationservice object by just adding the service reference.
This works when I run it on visual studio while debugging, but when I copy the exe on the server and run it gives error:
The caller was not authenticated by the service.::Inner Exception::The request for security token could not be satisfied because authentication failed.
At line: contactEntityCollection = client.RetrieveMultiple(fetchExp);
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever security context the exe is running under on the server will need to be a valid user in CRM.  If it's a windows service set the account to a user other than LocalSystem in the services MMC tool.  If it's running as a web application set the Application Pool to the dedicated account.  If it's a scheduled task set it in the configuration of the task.

You can also specify an instance of the ClientCredential class providing username and password but I'd highly recommend you avoid this route as you'll be responsible for securing the password within your application.

Comment: Hi,I am using below line to validate user and it is a valid CRM user, that's why it works when I debug the solution locally. orgProxy.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(userName, password, domain);

Comment: How to find "Which security context the exe is running under on the server", at least it is not using the user I am providing in the config?

Comment: Depends on the method of hosting the exe.  I covered how to determine what these are in my answer.  If you're using hardcoded values from config those shouldn't matter anyway although you might want to check the permissions of this account if it's not a local admin on the server.  Have you verified the values are being read from config correctly and that those values are correct?